# rxjs 5.5 filter is not a function (angular 5 lazy loading)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-cli

I have a very strange problem. Everything works fine without lazy loading (with aot).

I've done these steps to make my module laze loaded:

1. Change in app routing: `loadChildren: 'app/calls/calls.module#CallsModule',`
2. Check app - everything is fine
3. Remove in app.module my module:

   `@NgModule({
       imports: [
           // CallsModule,
       ],
   })
   export class AppModule {
   }`
4. And then I got error:

`app.component.html:10 ERROR TypeError: this.fullDataStream.filter is not a function`

`this.fullDataStream` is `rxjs/Subject`.

I tried to replace `.filter` to `.pipe(filter())` But my code is not working any more (`ReplaySubject` doesn't replay items).

What is wrong? Its' me or typescript/angular/angular-cli/rxjs bug?

`Angular 5.0.1
RxJS 5.5.2
Typescript 2.4.2
angular-cli 1.5.0`

UPD:
With imported `CallModule`, `ReplaySubject` doesn't replay value when lazy loading

Comment: I guess, I found what is wrong. Answer later then I'll be sure

Answer (score 0):

So there was two problems.

1. `filter` actually should be used with `pipe()` wrapper. Don't know why it worked before
2. My service was imported twice, that's why ReplaySubject doesn't replay items. new instance doesn't have any. Read more: [Angular2 Lazy Loading Service being Instantiated Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290275/angular2-lazy-loading-service-being-instantiated-twice) 
   https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#q-why-bad