# Why is my @Injectable service created more than once?

Tags: angular, typescript

> **Note:** Please scroll  down to the "Update" as the issue was boiled down to a `@Injectable` service being instanciated more than once.

I have a resolver that loads businesses:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
  this._logger.debug('Loading application data.');
  return forkJoin([
    this._userService.getMe(),
    this._businessService.getAll()
  ]).pipe(
    tap(([user, businesses]) => {
      this._appState.user = user;
      this._appState.businesses = businesses;
    }),
    finalize(() => this._logger.debug('Application data loaded.'))
  );
}
```

There is an `ApplicationState` that has two `BehaviorSubject` members `_business` and `_businesses`:

```
constructor() {
  this.businessChange = this._business.asObservable();
  this.businessesChange = this._businesses.asObservable();
}

set business(business: BusinessModel) {
  console.log(business);
  this._business.next(business);
}

get business(): BusinessModel {
  return this._business.getValue();
}

set businesses(value) {
  this._businesses.next(value);
  console.log(this.businesses);
}

get businesses(): Array<BusinessModel> {
  return this._businesses.getValue();
}
```

As you can see, `businesses` of said state gets set in the resolver. `business` however depends on the route and gets set in a (lazy-loaded) module depending on that route:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this._appState.businessesChange.subscribe(
    (b) => {
      console.log('businessesChange');
      console.log(b);
    }
  );

  this._subscriptions.add(
    this._activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe((params) => {
        this._routeParams = params;
        const businessId: number = parseInt(params['businessId'], 10);
        const businesses = this._appState.businesses;
        console.log(`businessId ${businessId}`);
        console.log('available businesses');
        console.log(businesses);
        this._appState.business = businesses.find(b => b.id === businessId);
      })
  );
}
```

This is the relevant log output:

```
2019-08-28T09:11:04.989Z DEBUG [..~df7ced28.js:428] Loading application data.
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:11:04.992Z DEBUG [main.js:398] Fetching /me
application.state.ts:56 Set businesses:
application.state.ts:58 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:11:06.781Z DEBUG Application data loaded.
businesses.component.ts:43 businessesChange
businesses.component.ts:44 []
businesses.component.ts:47 businessId 4
businesses.component.ts:48 available businesses
businesses.component.ts:49 []
application.state.ts:46 Set business:
application.state.ts:47 undefined
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:11:08.386Z DEBUG Place is null. No action.
```

As you can see, `businesses` gets set and contains three elements. Then we see that *Application data loaded.* from the resolver. After that, we see the `_activatedRoute.params` subscription stating that the route reveals a `businessId` of `4` but then.. `this._appState.businesses` is all of a sudden an empty list - the initial value of the `BehaviorSubject` even though we printed that out a few moments earlier.

Since I am logging/debuggin the `set` methods as well, I can see that this value does **not** get changed after being set to that list of three elements.

I have no idea what's going on here. What could possibly cause this?

---

What I already tried:

- Restart the server
- Use the debugger (but I printf-debug anyway)

---

#### Update

Okay I have boiled the issue down to the `ApplicationState` being instanciated more than once:

By giving the `ApplicationState` a simple ID (timestamp):

```
constructor() {
  this.businessChange = this._business.asObservable();
  this.businessesChange = this._businesses.asObservable();
  this.timestamp = moment().format('MM.SS SSS');
  console.log(`${this.timestamp} ApplicationState created`);
}
```

and changing the log-output in the `set` and `get` methods, I get this:

```
08.09 095 ApplicationState created
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:51:16.098Z DEBUG Loading application data.
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:51:16.099Z DEBUG [main.js:398] Fetching /me
:4200/#/businesses/4/calendar:1 This site does not have a valid SSL certificate! Without SSL, your site's and visitors' data is vulnerable to theft and tampering. Get a valid SSL certificate before releasing your website to the public.
application.state.ts:60 08.09 095 Set businesses:
application.state.ts:62 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
application.state.ts:38 08.14 145 ApplicationState created
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:51:16.161Z DEBUG Application data loaded.
businesses.component.ts:43 businessesChange
businesses.component.ts:44 []
businesses.component.ts:54 businessId 4
businesses.component.ts:55 available businesses
businesses.component.ts:56 []
application.state.ts:50 08.14 145 Set business:
application.state.ts:51 undefined
ngx-logger.js:251 2019-08-28T09:51:16.178Z DEBUG Place is null. No action.
calendar.component.ts:105
```

So there is a `08.09 095` (A) and a `08.14 145` (B) instance of `ApplicationState`.

A gets the businesses set but further B is used apparently.

I checked, `ApplicationState` gets imported only once in my `ApplicationModule`:

```
providers: [
  // Services
  ApplicationState,
  ApiServices,
  ApplicationResolver,
]
```

So why is this happening? Shouldn't this be Singleton? Is it because this goes over a lazy-loaded module?

But most importantly: Why did this work for the last few weeks?

I also added `providedIn` by now:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApplicationState {
```

but it still behaves the same.

Comment: What if you actually subscribe to the behaviorsubjects when retrieving the value, are the businesses still emtpy?

Comment: @JelleBruisten Just tried it.. it's still empty O_o

Comment: @JelleBruisten I updated the log-output and the code. `businessesChange` is the observable of `_businesses`.

Comment: Seems like the behaviorSubject value is not updated, the behaviorsubject should always put out the latest value even on a new subscribtion. Therefore It seems maybe the applicationState object is not the same as the one used before?

Comment: @JelleBruisten Yes, I just checked this (see my update). Apparently it gets instanciated twice? Should this happen? I thoguth injectables are singleton and get instanciated only once?

Comment: .. and ffs I don't know how long I am doing it like this already. This worked for weeks and like an hour ago it broke. I can't recall doing something related to this behavior. I implemented a FormControl and all of a sudden.. boom ..

Comment: Indeed it seems like because it's lazyloaded/in other modules

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the answer *why* this happened was apparently due to lazy loading. It seems to have something to do how the dependency tree gets build or something like that.

I do not know the details and I would accept any anser which is more detailed about this topic.

Anyway, I thought it should be enough to provide the service in a *parent* module. Because it makes sence, doesn't it?

Turns out that this really has to be provided in the `app.module.ts`. I have another module, called `application.module.ts` (should not be confused) where I provided `ApplicationState`. `application.module.ts` is lazy loaded but also has some routes which are again lazy loaded e.g. `businesses.module.ts`. So my hierarchy looks something like this:

```
app.module.ts
|_ application.module.ts  // lazy, providers: [ApplicationState]
|  |_ businesses.ts       // lazy, uses ApplicationState too
|_ public-pages.module.ts // not lazy
```

and what I had to change was to set

```
providers: [ApplicationState]
```

in `app.module.ts`.

This is not ideal imo but since lazy loading works like this I'll have to deal with it.

Apparently this is a known issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12869) but there is also a possible solution on stack**overflow**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41293784/826983