# Cannot get BehaviourSubject value even if it is set in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I cannot understand why the data set by parent component is not obtained on the child component by the following approach. I have used this approach many times, but I have really no idea what the problem:

***parent component:***

```
setData() {
    this.dataService.setDataSubject('test');
}
```

***data.service:***

```
private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

getDataSubject(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
  return this.dataSubject;
}

setDataSubject(param: any) {
  this.dataSubject.next(param);
}
```

***child component:***

```
testData: any;


constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getDataSubject().subscribe(data => {
    // <-- it is not triggered after parent's setData() method 
    // is called (except first page load)
    debugger; 
    if (data) {
      this.testData = data;
    }
  });
}
```

I also tried something using something like `public data$: Observable<any> = this.dataSubject;` using `Observable`.

***Update:***

Here is my module relationship:

***parent.module:***

```
imports: [
  SharedModule
],
providers: []
```

***child.module:***

```
imports: [
  SharedModule
],
providers: []
```

***shared.module:***

```
providers: [
    DataService
]
```

When I update as shown above, it still does not work. However, if I move `DataService` in the providers field from `shared.module` to `app.module` it works. But I think it should work when it is only in `shared.module` as shown above. Why?

Comment: Are you sure both components are using the same `DataService` instance?

Comment: `dataService.setData` is undefined? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorry, it is actually `this.dataService.setDataSubject('test')` and there is no problem in the project. I also corrected it on the question.

Comment: Then two possibilities I think, either you call `setData()` before the child component has subscribed to it, or as @martin said, make sure you are using the same instance of the service in both components

Comment: @JeremyThille I checked, but first child component subscribes and then I trigger the `setData` method. I do not understand what do you mean with "using the same instance of the service in both components ". I inject the service instance on the constructor of them. Any mistake with this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had issues with this at some point. It turned out that I was injecting my service, but Angular was creating a different instance of the service each time. Problem solved by adding `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in the service, so it became a singleton

Comment: Thanks, but  already use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in my service. Any idea?

Comment: Might it be that your child component is lazy-loaded? If so, check this up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290275/angular2-lazy-loading-service-being-instantiated-twice

Comment: Not child, but parent component is lazy loaded.